# Prove that a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function in $[a,b]$ with $f(a) =f(b)$ has this limit

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, probability-limit-theorems

Could you help me with it?

> Prove that if $f \in \mathcal{C}^1([a,b])$ with $f(a) = f(b)$ then
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b f(x) \sin nx \, \mathrm{d} x = 0
> $$

Thank you.

Comment: This is an absolutely standard result that is in virtually any book that handles Fourier analysis; what have you tried, and what is giving you difficulty?

Comment: @user61527 : Do we need fourier analysis for this? I do not know any fourier analysis and i found this question interesting...I could not handle this question... Can you give me some hint...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik This is a special case of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, which is one of the first results in many books on Fourier analysis. For class $C^1$, the picture is that uniform continuity means that $f$ is essentially constant over each oscillation of $\sin nx$, and so the integral over one period is $\approx 0$.

Comment: @user61527 : I am sorry that i do not understand what oscillation is and all... Can it be made less technical.. (If not that is alright)....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik By "oscillation," I mean that $\sin$ goes back and forth between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: This is basically the horizontal change in the function; f_{max}-f_{min}

Comment: @user61527 : Yes.. i think i understood... I will try to solve this...

Comment: @user99680 : May be you are making it too technical... I understood some how what the other user is trying to convey and i hope i could solve this.... thank you

Comment: Do integration by parts to get 1/n int f' cos (nx) do.   Then let n go to infinity.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik; No problem, good luck solving it.

Comment: @breeden and what about the boundary terms?

Comment: @DanZimm, right, I overlooked that it was from $[a,b]$ and not from, say, $[0,2\pi]$ where the assumption that $f(a) = f(b)$ would ensure that the boundary term is 0.  But the idea still works.  But it does make me wonder what the problem writer had in mind with assuming $f(a) = f(b)$ now...  My guess is that $a - b$ was assumed to be some multiple of $2\pi$.  *shrugs*

Comment: @breeden nah, it still works - on the boundary you'll get $-f(a)(\cos(nb)-\cos(na))/n$ and then you can bound the $\cos$ terms by $-2,2$ and finally take $n\to\infty$. Just was saying, it's not completely trivial (at least IMO).

Comment: @DanZimm I understand that it still works, but it's not clear to me why $f(a) = f(b)$ was assumed.  In my experience most problems have a method in mind when they write down the criteria, and I'm just not sure why they thought $f(a) = f(b)$ in the method they had in mind.  Certainly the $C^1([a,b])$ criteria screams integration by parts, and often a $f(a) = f(b)$ criteria is thrown in there to ensure that the boundary terms disappear.  It's not clear what they had in mind here.  It's possible there was an error in transcribing the problem, or just a mistake while writing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma under much weaker conditions, but just assume $f \in C([a,b])$.  Choose a partition $a=x_0 < x_1 < \dots, x_m=b.$

Then

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\sin nx \, dx=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j}[f(x)-f(x_j)]\sin nx\,dx + \sum_{j=1}^{m}\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j}f(x_j)\sin nx\,dx$$

and using the triangle inequality

$$\Big|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\sin nx \, dx\Big|\leq \\ \sum_{j=1}^{m}\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j}|f(x)-f(x_j)||\sin nx|\,dx + \sum_{j=1}^{m}|f(x_j)|\frac{|\cos nx_j-\cos nx_{j-1}|}{n} \\ \leq \sum_{j=1}^{m}\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_j}|f(x)-f(x_j)|\,dx + \sum_{j=1}^{m}|f(x_j)|\frac{2}{n}$$

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ it is bounded and uniformly continuous. Hence there exist  $M > 0$ such that for all $x \in [a,b],$

$$|f(x)| \leq M,$$

and for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that  for all $|x-y| < \delta,$

$$|f(x)-f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}.$$

Let the norm of the partition be less than $\delta$.

Then

$$\Big|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\sin nx \, dx\Big|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} +  \frac{2Mm}{n}.$$

For all $n > 4Mm/\epsilon$, we have

$$\Big|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\sin nx \, dx\Big|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} +  \frac{\epsilon}{2}= \epsilon,$$

and

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\sin nx \, dx=0$$

Comment: I'm sorry RRL, but I feel that this solution is far more complicated than it needs to be.  Certainly the $C^1([a,b])$ case allows for an easy integration by parts.  If you wanted to extend this to the continuous case, you can approximate continuous functions by $C^1$ functions, and the extension is straight forward.  However, on that note, I do like your proof :)

Comment: It's a good point.  At the time, there were some partial answers using integration by parts so I thought I'd give another perspective. The uniform approximation by $C^1$ functions requires some work too.  Also breaking the integral into a sum is a generally useful technique.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
u = f(x) & v = ? \\
\mathrm{d} u = ? & \mathrm{d} v = \sin nx \, \mathrm{d} x
\end{array}
$$
$$
-1 \le \cos u \le 1 \, \forall u \in \mathbb{R}
$$